# Configuration Manager only shows Debug

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration, build-environment

I am working in Visual Studio 2008 on an ASP.NET application, which has been deployed to a test server.  I would like to make a build without debug information to place in production, but the configuration manager only shows "Debug" in the configuration dropdown for my project.

My other Visual Studio projects show "Debug", "Release", "New...", and "Edit...".

Why do I not see a release option, or the new and edit commands?

Comment: did you solve this problem

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG the details have faded, it was almost a decade ago.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ASP.NET web sites do not use the configuration manager to determine if debug information is included in the compile. You must set it in the `web.config` file. Visual Studio will never change debug to "false" for you automactially, as far as I know.

Find this section in your `web.config` file and change it to "false":

```
<!--
    Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
    symbols into the compiled page. Because this
    affects performance, set this value to true only
    during development.
-->

<compilation debug="true">
```

Visual Studio will ask you if you want it changed from false to true if you are running your web site in the IDE, but unfortunately it does not do the reverse for publishing (which seems more important to me).

If you have multiple projects in your solution, and at least one of them supports a release configuration (such as a DLL) - it will appear in the configuration drop-down list. Building with Release selected still does not affect the website, however.

Comment: I changed my web.config of my WCF-Service project, but still cannot see "Release" in my dropdown. Are any other steps required?

Comment: @slartidan If you set debug="false", that's all you need to do. The dropdown is irrelevant.

Comment: PS: In my Visual Studio solution file I had to change my "Webpage" to a "Project" to be able to see and use "Release" and "Debug". I needed it for web.config transformation.

Comment: this is different thing than publishing

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the best answer and wrestling with this problem for a couple of hours, I ran across this answer.  My solution was to add a full application: usually use an empty web site, but had the same problem of the release not displaying.  I added a full application to the solution and it then allowed me to deploy my project within the solution, since adding the complete application also added the option of 'release' in the dropdown.  I very much appreciate the advice, but not sure why this tool is so quirky.  Thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration Manager for the Solution allows you to delete either (or both) of these default build configurations (through the Edit... option you mention above). I would bet that someone deleted the Release configuration.

You can get it back by recreating it, or copy the appropriate lines from a solution you make from scratch real quick. A file diff shows the following:

Default solution file:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```

Solution after I manually deleted the Release configuration:

```
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {EDD50911-B94E-49A4-A08B-A2E91228A04B}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
My solution file still has the two lines for release, so this is not the issue.

Comment: Looking at this the opposite way, "does adding those lines to a .sln file cause  those configurations to show up for projects in VS?" The answer is no. VS (at least 2015) won't use those names against the projects in the Configuration Manager window unless the project file has the corresponding PropertyGroup with a condition attached: `<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'MyConfigName|x86'" />`. The configuration name must be a literal, and it must be in the project file and not an imported targets file.

Answer (score 0):

the process was changed, you just need to check the 2 bottom check boxes during the settings part of the publish process, as shown in the image. in the bin folder you'll find the dlls.

[image]

hope that helps

eiran

Comment: This did not fix the issue for me