# How can I set up different build configurations for ASP.Net web site projects?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, configuration, build-environment

According to [an earlier question about Visual Studio configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259311/configuration-manager-only-shows-debug), there's no way to use Visual Studio's configuration manager to create different configurations for an ASP.net web site project.

For normal projects, we have #if directives that switch certain server or database variables depending on whether we're debugging or in production.  This doesn't work for web sites.

For example, in a class (in App_Code) that defines a web site's back-end server connection, there might be a chunk of code like this which overrides production values in the web.config if you want to run a debug server on your local machine:

```
#if DEBUGLOCAL
           ServerProperties.ServerIP = "localhost";
           ServerProperties.DataContextIP = "localhost";
#endif
```

This doesn't work, since there's no "Debug Local" configuration for the website, thus no DEBUGLOCAL defined.

Have you found a good way to work around problems like this?  Besides (I hope) refactoring everything so all those references live in a class library project?

ETA: Can [web deployment projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a Web Deployment project that does some swapping in the web.config may be of some help?  Another thought would be to have a connection string in the web.config that pulls various values from a pre-specified database that can exist in each environment to allow for easy changes to the settings without needing to touch any files.

Comment: I hadn't heard of web deployment projects (I'm still kind of new to this stuff).  Microsoft's download link is here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en

Comment: Scott Gutherie's blog usually has the latest and greatest ASP.Net stuff and is where I heard of Web Deployment Projects. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/ is a link to his blog, which now has lots of ASP.Net MVC and Silverlight stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Another option may be to [upgrade the web site to a web application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/05/437439.aspx).

That could be a lot of work to make the transition now, but the ability to have configurations may help tip the scales if you're deciding to go with a web site or web application.