# VS2010 debug/release.config not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config

I'm having a bit of trouble with my `web.debug.config` and `web.release.config` files.

To be more specific, my webpage will only use the default `web.config` file, and completely ignore the `debug` and `release` files.
This happens not only when I run the project locally, but also when I publish it to an IIS server.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (no Service Pack).

Here are the config files:

**`web.config`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConn" connectionString="SomeConnectionString"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**`web.debug.config` and `web.release.config`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns:xtd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConn" connectionString="SomeOtherConnectionString"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
            xtd:Transform="Replace"
            xtd:Locator="Match(name)"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

As I mentioned before, the website uses the connection string from the `web.config` file, and not from the `web.release.config`.

Another interesting point is that in the physical folder to which I published the project, all three `config` files exist; each exactly the same as they appear in the VS solution.

Suggestions, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I have been doing wrong.

Instead of a **Web Application**, I was using a **Web Site Project**.

(The difference between the two is that a **Project** doesn't actually contain a `.proj` file. How ironic.)

Now that I've realized the actual problem, it turns out that I'm not the first with it...
Here's a link to a previous post with a workaround solution:

[How do I do Web.config Transformations with Visual Studio Website Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082126/how-do-i-do-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-website-projects)

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the transformations. It will not work if you just put the 3 web.config in your folder. You can run this and it will transform your web.config

```
MSBuild.exe Project.csproj /T:TransformWebConfig /P:Configuration=Release
```

You will then have a folder in your obj folder created at build that will be called TransformWebConfig. The transformed web.config will be in this.

You can also take a look at this post, he creates a build target to achieve this automatically.

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/05/applying-xdt-magic-to-appconfig.html

Comment: I didn't add the config files manually; Visual Studio created them automatically.

Comment: Yep but you still need to run the transformation. If you follow the steps in the blogpost I sent you it shoud work just fine

Comment: Alas, I can't complete the steps in the blogpost; the post explains how to make an `App.Debug.config` file act just as a `Web.Debug.config` file -- it doesn't resolve the web issue I have.
Moreover, many of the steps are irrelevant with a web application.