# c# visual studio ultimate 2013 asp.net website release deployment

Tags: c#, web, release, web-deployment

I have created a webpage using VS Ultimate 2013. I Don't see a web.release.config
How do I create a release build with binaries and upload to my production server?
Eugene

Comment: If you click on your project, then click on the 'View' menu and select 'Property Pages' and select the 'Build' tab do you have an option for Release under the 'Configuration' drop down?

Comment: Under Build tab, there is no 'Configuration drop box.

Answer (score 1):

You should publish your website. Click right mouse button on your project, select publish and use the wizard for publication. From this wizard you may publish it directly to microsoft azure or build publication package to the file system and then deploy it manually to any place.

Comment: When I deploy to a different release folder, It does some work and fills the new folder with source code as it is. I need the release files as dll.

Answer (score 0):

The Web.Release.config is just configuration transform applied when a project is built release configuration.

To select that you wish to use the Release configuration you need to change your build configuration. This is typically done via a dropdown on the toolbar but you can also do it in the publish menu or in Build->Configuration Manager.

There are more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kkz9kefa.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. But, my Build->Configuration Manager or the tool bar does not have "Release" option at all. I see only debug.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have Visual Basic Development Settings applied. These are set at the time Visual Studio is installed and you select what your primary programming language is. To view the configuration settings try:

- Clicking 'Tools' > 'Options'.
- Expand 'Projects and Solutions' and click 'General'.
- Click 'Show advanced build configurations'.

This should make the Configuration drop down visible to you on the 'Build' tab ('View' > 'Property Pages').

Here some more info: 
[Understanding Build Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) and
[How to: Manage Build Configurations with Visual Basic Developer Settings Applied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms165414.aspx)

***EDIT***

Read your question again. Try reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259311/configuration-manager-only-shows-debug). In case the question is deleted basically, as you're deploying a website the configuration manager isn't used to determine whether it should be in debug or not. You need to do it in the web.config file. There should be a section that says:

```
<compilation debug="true">
```

I think by default this is true and you will need to change this to false.

Comment: 'Show advanced build configurations' is already enabled. The tool bar has on two options. 'Debug' and 'Configuration Manager'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 'Pre compilation' is the one I was looking for. When I enabled it while publishing it, it compiled all the cs files in to the 'Bin' folder and my source code is safe.
Eugene