# Manual config transform as TFS build step

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, vs-web-site-project

I have a solution file that contains a web site project (among other project types). It uses a publish profile for deployment and I'm trying to move the entire thing to TFS (2015) to automate the build and deploy process. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259311/configuration-manager-only-shows-debug) I cannot manage the build configuration since it is a web site project and consequently cannot use the [Web.config Transformation feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'd like to execute some sort of transform, perhaps as a build step. I can manually create and maintain the web.release.config file but don't know how to manually transform it. Does an XLST file exist to transform it outside of Visual Studio (e.g. a cmd build step to call an XSLT processor)?

**Addendum**: converting to a web project would most definitely fix the issue but not a solution for me as that would require involvement from the remote contractors contributing to our code base - a TFS build-level solution is the only thing I'm looking for.

Comment: You should change your project to a Web Application to gain additional features as well as stability and consistency in your application.

Comment: Does CeCe's solution solve your issue?

Comment: I don't think it will, since it would require either an additional base file (causing the web.config used during development to not be referenced during the build process) or it would require the tokens to be stored in the web.config file itself, rendering the web.config useless during development unless a local-only post-build step was added to also perform Replace Tokens locally (if I'm understanding the plugin correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my actual transforms were relatively simple I developed this XSL transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="xformPath">web.Prod.config</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="xform" select="document($xformPath)"></xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="output-transform">
    <xsl:param name="xformNode" />
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="@key" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$xformNode">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$xformNode" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/configuration/appSettings/add">
    <xsl:variable name="key" select="@key" />
    <xsl:call-template name="output-transform">
      <xsl:with-param name="xformNode" select="$xform/configuration/appSettings/add[@key=$key]" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="@name" />
    <xsl:call-template name="output-transform">
      <xsl:with-param name="xformNode" select="$xform/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name=$name]" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/configuration/system.web/customErrors">
    <xsl:call-template name="output-transform">
      <xsl:with-param name="xformNode" select="$xform/configuration/system.web/customErrors" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That has some obvious shortcomings,

- Items to be replaced must be manually defined
- Replaces with the entire element, not only the specified attributes
- Does not maintain children elements (e.g. I tried to change `system.web/compilation@debug` to `false` but I lost all my `system.web/compilation/assemblies` entries)

I plan to add this in a Command Line step, between my Visual Studio Build step and Copy Files step, and call either msxsl.exe or Saxon's HE transform engine.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrHinsh mentioned in comment, it's suggested to create a Web Application project instead of a Web Site project, as Web Site project doesn't have web.release.config file by default, while a Web Application project has.

To replace tokens in files with variable values, you can add a [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task in your build definition.

[image]